# microsoft azure clearing cookies after application terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, cookies, azure-mobile-services

I have implemented `microsoft azure` sdk for authentication in our app. All done well.

But when user logged out I used this code

```
    NSError *error;
    [[ADKeychainTokenCache defaultKeychainCache] removeAllForClientId:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"azureClientId"] error:&error];
```

So if user stays on active and again if he would logs in then `microsoft azure` is able to get user info without entering credentials again.

but when app terminates and open again, asking for password.

I dont want to ask credentials again.

Is there any problem with my logout code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't generally log out of a social provider - the functionality does not exist.  Explicitly, the auth information is stored in the UIWebView, generally as a cookie.  This is then passed onto the auth provider next time and the auth provider uses this information to silently authenticate you.

Comment: That would work if you can make it happen.  It would also make your mobile app log the user out of all apps using the same authentication method.  I'm not sure they would like you for that.